# ビルドしたAndroidのOSイメージを実機に入れたい (failed to load/verify boot images)

Tags: android

ビルドしたAndroidOSイメージを実機(Pixel3a)に入れたいです。
バージョンはAndroid9.0で、タグ(ブランチ)はandroid-9.0.0_r47です。Pixel3aがサポートされています([参考](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds))
[ドキュメント](https://source.android.com/setup/build/running)通りに行い、fastboot(fastbootd)モードで`fastboot flashall -w`とコマンドを叩くと

```
yamakentoc:/home/yamakentoc/:~$ fastboot flashall -w
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: b4s4-0.2-5736883
Baseband Version.....: g670-00030-191028-B-5972069
Serial Number........: 94LAY0R0QK
--------------------------------------------
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.000s]
Setting current slot to 'b'                        OKAY [  0.081s]
Sending 'boot_b' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  1.690s]
Writing 'boot_b'                                   OKAY [  0.434s]
Sending 'dtbo_b' (8192 KB)                         OKAY [  0.211s]
Writing 'dtbo_b'                                   OKAY [  0.113s]
Sending 'vbmeta_b' (4 KB)                          OKAY [  0.001s]
Writing 'vbmeta_b'                                 OKAY [  0.002s]
Resizing 'product_b'                               OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'system_b'                                OKAY [  0.004s]
Resizing 'vendor_b'                                OKAY [  0.004s]
Resizing 'system_b'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 1/3 (524284 KB)          OKAY [ 13.756s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  3.394s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 2/3 (524284 KB)          OKAY [ 13.701s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  3.619s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 3/3 (133160 KB)          OKAY [  3.476s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  1.217s]
Sending 'system_a' (91744 KB)                      OKAY [  2.375s]
Writing 'system_a'                                 OKAY [  0.615s]
Erasing 'userdata'                                 OKAY [  0.062s]
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Erasing 'metadata'                                 OKAY [  0.005s]
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Rebooting                                          OKAY [  0.000s]
Finished. Total time: 44.881s
yamakentoc:/home/yamakentoc/:~$
```

このようにエラーは出ず、しっかりと入った(多分)と思います。これで起動するはずですが...
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
fastbootモードが起動し、画面には`Enter reazon: failed to load/verify boot images`と出ます。

何がいけないのでしょうか？
画像でわかると思いますが、ブートローダーのアンロックはしています。
`ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/home/yamakentoc/AOSP/out/target/product/sargo/`と指定もしてます。

ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/227921

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました！
↓のサイトからバイナリハードウェアサポートファイルをルートディレクトリにDLする必要がありました！
https://developers.google.com/android/drivers

詳しいことはQiitaにまとめました
https://qiita.com/yamakentoc/items/564108cd5ad207193f0e